# Is it ok if a colleague adds a bounty to my question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I am working in an organization which does not have much leadership help so Stack Overflow is one of the premium platforms for me.

I have a question which did not attract much attention. My fellow colleague and I are both on Stack Overflow, but as I don't have much reputation I cannot offer a bounty on my question.

Can my colleague offer a bounty on my question? Is it legal as per the terms and conditions of Stack Overflow?

Comment: If it wasn't 'legal', then why would the system allow you to do it?

Comment: @GEOCHET The question is if it's allowed for _specifically his colleague_ to do it, not for anyone else to do it. The system can't tell that they're working together, so it can't ban that kind of behavior except through T&C, which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Not only is it legal, but they even get a badge for doing it. And then another for awarding it!

Comment: Woop woop.. That is the sound of the (bounty) police. Be happy that someone is giving up their points for an answer.

Comment: Just never vote for each other questions or answers

Comment: "The question is if it's allowed for specifically his colleague to do it" - The system cannot tell the difference. So why would the system care?

Comment: @IanRingrose: not quite. They should not vote on each other's posts simply because they are colleagues. But there's no harm in them casting legitimate votes based on genuine assessments of those posts. As long as they are not specifically monitoring each other's posts (e.g. because they are colleagues), this will result in normal voting patterns and won't trigger any flags or contravene any specific rules. If they are specifically monitoring each other's posts, they will need to be extra careful to only vote on posts that they otherwise would have come across through normal use of the site.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, the problem is that they are working on the same project and talking to each other about issues, so at least for questions they are more likely to know about each other questions then "random" people would.   Also as they have the same problems, they are likely to find each other questions interesting.    Trying to vote "normally" in such cases is very hard if not impossible.    (As bounty are used by voting rings and hence increase the risk the system thinks they are a voting ring, best to reduce the risk as much as possible.)

Comment: @GEOCHET Your "the system lets you do it, therefore it must be legal" reasoning does not work here. The site lets you do all kinds of things that are actually against the rules. Some get reversed automatically later (serial voting) others get handled only if a human notices (posting spam, mis-using bounties to transfer rep to a specific person, etc).

Comment: Your colleague seems to have a genuine interest in getting your question answered (if only to advance your common goal), so I would say this is totally OK. But please don't thank him by upvoting his contributions without need. This would not be ethical.

Comment: I'm sure that this question drew attention to the other question... Actually it's pretty clever!

Answer (score 144, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

> You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.

Doing so is perfectly legal, [*unless*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169834/transferring-reputation-to-another-user-by-rewarding-bounties/169835#169835) you somehow intend to answer the question yourself and earn the bounty, thereby transferring reputation from your colleague to you.

Comment: "unless you somehow intend to answer the question yourself and earn the bounty" Is this actually specifically addressed anywhere in the help center, or are you just making it up?

Comment: @Zack don't know about help but see e.g.  [Transferring reputation to another user by rewarding bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169834/transferring-reputation-to-another-user-by-rewarding-bounties)

Comment: @Zack It's pretty clear to a reasonable person that this would be an unreasonable use of the bounty system

Comment: @TimMalone I agree. There is a mod response from BoltClock in that answer that stuartd posted: ["Correct: this is a suspendable offense assuming we find evidence that bounties are being abused for the transfer of reputation"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169835/231494)

Comment: It's sad that we've come to a point where these things have to be spelled out... this is why I couldn't bring myself to upvote Aziz's answer even though it too was directly answering the question.

Comment: @BoltClock unfortunate but yes ... you are right. I have edited my post and tried to address the misuse case by quoting a post from MSE.

Comment: "unless you somehow intend to answer the question yourself and earn the bounty"  Sound like nonsense.  Could you ***Include a link*** showing where SO says this is the case?

Comment: "It's pretty clear to a reasonable person that this would be an unreasonable use of the bounty system"  That seems odd, Tim ... the one and only reason for the existence of the SO bounty system in this universe, is so that SO (which is an advertising business) gets more traffic and hence makes more money from advertising.  It's not immediately clear that such restrictions would increase traffic?  Usually "more control" (of any form) means "less traffic", you know.

Comment: @AzizShaikh's answer has a direct link to the actual question.

Comment: @JoeBlow The purpose of the bounty system is so that someone who wants to provide an incentive for a question to be answered beyond the usual for accepted answers, at their own expense, can do so. It encourages participation, not just viewing. (Whether or not it actually works the way it's supposed to is an orthogonal topic.)

Comment: hi @jab, the purpose of any feature on a business such as this is to "make more money" which is pretty much equivalent to saying "get more users, more traffic, more views, more [as you say] participation".

Comment: @JoeBlow And part of making money is maintaining a good reputation (in general, at least) and ensuring that those who provide your means of making money stick around to make you money. Which means moderation and protection against abuse.

Comment: hi @jab.  Well that's a business opinion; yours.  Fair enough.  I'd say there are many, many, examples where the more open, free-wheeling, a system is, the more it attracts users.  (It would be easy to say this is one of the basic paradigms of the dotcom-to-social-disease era.)

Comment: It might do your answer justice to note *all* of BoltClock's response to the meta question. Answering the question that his colleague placed a bounty on is (supposedly) fine as long as there is no evidence that the bounties are being **abused**. Otherwise, this answer is essentially saying "Even if your intentions are pure, if you discover the answer yourself later, don't post it here or you'll get in trouble." I don't think we actually want to convey that kind of message here.

Answer (score 50):

**Can my colleague raise a bounty on my question?**

Yes, anyone can place a bounty on your question. This is also mentioned in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it

Stack Exchange treats this as a positive behavior, your colleague will receive the [*investor* badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor) for placing the bounty.

> First bounty you offer on another person's question.

---

Quoting [Tim Post♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) from his [answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175458/):

> If you want to add a bounty to your friend's question in order for it
>   to receive an answer, there's absolutely no problem with that.
>
> Likewise, there'd be no problem placing a bounty to reward an
>   excellent answer that a friend wrote.

*but **beware**, [this should not be misused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175445/):*

> That said, if excessive, the patterns would be indistinguishable from
>   co-workers that tend to up-vote each other's posts quite frequently,
>   and we do contact people to warn them when we notice it. Just be sure
>   to show your appreciation for outstanding contributions as a matter of
>   habit