# Is this voting fraud; or how to understand some [android] question's version of quality?

Tags: support, specific-question, voting

Some months ago I brought to light a [very bad audit case originating from an Android question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299184/why-is-this-unclear-question-with-no-minimal-reproducible-example-or-error-messa). In essence: a +8 question ended up in the review queue whereas it should have been downvoted and closed. At the time, rene [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299184/why-is-this-unclear-question-with-no-minimal-reproducible-example-or-error-messa#comment219973_299184) that some dev should look at the strange voting pattern.

Earlier today, I opened an unanswered question from the Stack Overflow weekly newsletter, thinking to read some interesting things. I was somewhat disappointed to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372068/automatically-add-widget-to-home-screen-on-a-custom-android-rom):

> I'm creating a custom android ROM, and preloading my app into it (to /system/priv-app).
>   My app has a widget.
>   How can I make this widget appear on the home screen automatically?
>
> Thanks.

While it is not as bad as the first question I linked here, it is completely too broad, has no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and borders on unclear. I mean, without being stellar, *eight* upvotes on a question should be an indication of relative quality.

- Can someone with relevant android experience explain how this question is good?
- Are we witnessing voting circle fraud?
- Was there anything done to verify if some shady voting pattern is happening?

Comment: 7 upvotes in a 30 minute period, over a day after the question was posted, without any edits to bump the post... that seems a little bit odd.

Comment: If it smells loke a sock.....

Comment: It smells like a *ring*... yet it could still, theoretically, be a coincidence. Let's let the mods handle this.

Comment: @frederic ok then..... 4 pairs of socks? :p or a ring

Comment: You are mistaken.  **This question is not broad at all** - deployment of apps as part of a custom system image is a very specific thing, and an ordinary part of generating such a custom build.

Comment: You mention that it has no MCVE, but I don't see how an MCVE would be useful for this question

Comment: @TZHX "I opened an unanswered question from the Stack Overflow weekly newsletter" - those voters probably did the same...

Comment: @Izkata I assume the newsletter selects questions based on the score, and wouldn't select a question sitting at -1.

Comment: @TZHX That I have no idea, but it could totally explain a jump in the number of votes

Comment: @Izkata while your interest *is* interesting (..) the votes **were** reversed. If they came from different ips, timezones ant stuff, they wouldn't have been reversed. the jump was caused by a concerted effort. that part is clear.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**"Can someone with relevant android experience explain how this question is good?"**

Indeed, this question is good in purpose (though it could be better in form) - but before getting into that, let's look at why the "voting ring" explanation is so wrong - *even if* a bunch of co-workers might have upvoted it in quick succession.

Fundamentally, this is a question about a subject that is of *high* interest to a particular type of software developer, and *no interest* to anyone else.  In fact, most people who have never put time into making custom builds of Android would not - like the poster here in meta - even have the perspective to approach the question at all.

**This question is not "broad" at all - in fact it is highly specific.**

Suffice to say that if you study the Android build system (the system which builds all the operating system and application software components that ship on the device from source and creates the system image), it becomes pretty clear that anything you do on your own when creating a customized build of Android should be modeled on how the existing parts get themselves into the image. There are widgets on the stock homescreen, and there is a specific mechanism by which they get there to discover and turn into a specific answer.

**The general problem with smaller specialties of development being mishandled on SO**

Stack Overflow's "crowd mentality" often badly mistreats questions in such specialized areas - especially in a case like this where a question looks *on careless reading* like something general (developing another Android app) but is actually about something unique and critically different (modifying Android itself).  And it only gets worse when the focus moves from those who found the question due to actual interest in the topic, to those who found it via administrative means - that is to say, those reading right now who are *sure* they know that this is a bad question, but have formed that opinion without spending the time to actually understand its subject matter.

**Upvoting a co-worker's question is not wrong**

See for example: [Is it ok if a colleague adds a bounty to my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323600/is-it-ok-if-a-colleague-adds-a-bounty-to-my-question)

In contrast, a "voting ring" is when people game the system to gain reputation (especially if one of them answers it and that answer gets rapid upvotes) - not when they happen to actually share the desire for an answer to a pressing question that remains unanswered.

If there were any remaining doubt, consider this - does an asker who has had an account for five years while collecting only a few hundred reputation points really look like someone who cares enough about collecting reputation to try to game the system?

Comment: _"This question is not "broad" at all"_ You're saying the question should stay open? _And_ that 8 upvotes in quick succession isn't suspicious at all? The question is nothing but a feature request. No (research) effort is shown.

Comment: I would not be surprised if a team walked out of scrum the next day, logged in, and all upvoted their major blocker.  But that is entirely allowed.  As for research - go ahead, look, see what you find.  Probably 80% of questions asked on SO have an obvious and obviously untried path to resolution *in the eyes of a subject matter expert* but unless you know enough to know that the way you solve this is to see how android's creators solved it by reading their build scripts and code, *generic research* may get you nowhere.

Comment: A team upvoting a colleague's question would be considered a "voting ring", which isn't allowed. I'm not an Android expert and even I know the linked question's problem has probably been solved by a hundred people before. A quick search for _"android make app widget appear on home screen"_ returns plenty of resources.

Comment: @Cerbrus - read the question more carefully.  It is about the specific issue of making an application that is part of the system image have a widget already on the homescreen at first boot - ie, not about typical 3rd party app installation by the user.  (Though if you do happen to find a duplicate for precisely that, marking it as such would be a decent resolution)  As for upvoting a co-worker's question - no, see the link about putting a bounty on a co-worker's question.  If a question is important to someone in their judgement, they are allowed to upvote it, end of story.

Comment: Chris, the question you linked is about bounties, not about votes. Voting like you described is not allowed, and has gotten _loads_ of users banned.
So, maybe the question should've been closed as "Lacking MCVE" then. Either way, it's junk.

Comment: Wrong on both counts.  A voting "ring" involves feedback, specifically to artificially inflate questions your friends are going to answer.  This was fundamentally different - an outstanding problem multiple people considered important.  As for your opinion on the question, you've proven you can't be bother to understand it.  Many valid questions cannot *have* an MCVE - that is for *debugging* problems, which this is not.

Comment: "Stack Overflow's "crowd mentality" often badly mistreats questions in such specialized areas" I fully agree with that. Minority interests suffer a bit in a self governing system. But I still don't like the question much: it could explain more, be more specific about what it wants and show more own research. It should not be closed or deleted though. And separately, even for good question I would not like voting rings.

Comment: I fully agree with your answer, but it highlights another problem: The OP could have made the question much more clear. As it is now, the question is likely to be read as just another "How to get app on home screen?" question. By making it abundantly clear that it is about making a custom ROM and that the usual methods don't apply would improve the question greatly and remove this misinterpretation.

Comment: *"I would not be surprised if a team walked out of scrum the next day, logged in, and all upvoted their major blocker"* - really? Well I have worked in an MNC having more than 300000 employees. Is it fine if someone contacts the HR and sends a world wide mail asking to upvote a critical projects major blocker? I don't think so. That's not voting is for, that makes the reputation game absolutely meaningless. if you want attention, you put a **bounty**. Serial voting like this within few minutes is clearly for rep gain, not attention.

Comment: "high interest to a particular type of software developer, and no interest to anyone else." That is exactly the kind of questions we don't want on SO. Questions should be of some interest to other than the asker, otherwise, why should we be working as individuals free code service?

Comment: I agree with this answer, I have had a lot of questions where the question is too specific where at the best no one answers and at the worst I get lynched.

Comment: @Braiam That's not what he is saying. It is about a small field, not about 1 asker.

Comment: @Braiam It's not *that* specific. It's still a general problem you might have to solve, and useful to other people as well. It's not a problem you commonly have to solve (i.e. not a "mainstream" issue), but it's not specific to the OP either - anyone who creates an Android ROM with a custom application will face this. Just because fewf people care about Android ROMs doesn't mean the question doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: @Luaan [Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to **maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers**. If this means aggressively closing unworthy or uninteresting questions, so be it. *Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?*](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/595/41104)

Comment: @Braiam Your quote is out of context.  "_We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only..._"Jeff Atwood is saying that we are looking for questions which can be answered by the community and are useful to others.  While I will probably never need it, I am sure there are other Android ROM developers who will.

Comment: Hey there @ChrisStratton, thanks for taking the time to answer this. It is a really interesting point about the narrower specialties, I think I've fallen to that and will keep guard on it. However, I fully disagree with your comparison of votes and bounties. It is not ok for a concerted effort to vote up a single question to attract attention to it; that's precisely what **bounties** are for. Votes and bounties are not the same, and where a bounty is ok, a group effort to vote is not.

Comment: The very purpose of voting is to raise the visibility of good questions, especially those you want answers to. As long as it's not conspiracy or fraud, as in the voters acted independently, it should be allowed.

Comment: I agree with your first three points, but only partially with your last. If *one* coworker voted for one of your posts, that doesn't present much of a problem. But *eight* coworkers voting for your post, that has no other votes yet, makes a post look much more accepted by the community than it really is. It looks like a lot of people are interested in it and makes it more attractive, when what likely happened is someone said "hey all of you go upvote this so someone will answer it." That *is* a problem and needs to be corrected, which is what happened here.

Comment: @Trisped then how could you interpreted that the OP needed to game the system so his question reflects the "useful to others" part? I would say that if he didn't resort to that the question would have ended deleted without answer when the 30 days script ran. Closing it just expedited the date of arrival.

Comment: This is why I avoid moderating or voting on questions and answers outside of my expertise.

Comment: I'm uncertain about this really not being too broad of a question. In my (limited) experience with ROM development, a lot seems to be quite specific to exactly what you're trying to accomplish and given AOSP has such a large amount of code, it's unlikely that a tweak like this is going to fit well into the Stack Exchange format (perhaps more of a tutorial). I'm not positive on this obviously, but it does seem to be something to consider.

Comment: @Laurel the voters obviously voted in a concerted effort. Mods wouldn't have reversed votes simply because they felt like it; they have access to a range of informations we don't about votes and voters. Just saying because you seem to think that whole thing is ok, and that the votes weren't a ring of people that all agreed to vote at one point.

Comment: @Braiam You logic is hard to follow.  What proof is there that they were "gaming the system?"  How does that relate to your quote regarding the curation of questions which will have valuable answers?  In my mind, unless there is evidence that the 8 up voters are the same person using different accounts or part of a fraud ring, deleting the up-votes is inappropriate.

Comment: @Trisped maybe you missed the first comment on this question? 8 upvotes, in a 30 minutes time frame, without any edit to the post, are ***evidently*** an evidence of a concerted voting effort. I really don't understand how you can think otherwise.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I trust that the mods acted on evidence they had of wrongdoing. My point was that up voting a Q that you want to see answered (based off the Q's merits of course) is a legitimate use of voting. It is important to up vote good content so that it rises above the mediocre.

Comment: @Laurel Yes, absolutely! Upvoting a Q you legitimely want answered is a thing. Upvoting a Q with seven coworkers in a concerted effort is another thing.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier New questions are placed at the top of the list.  It is 100% possible that 8 different people read the question and up-voted it.  8 up-votes in 1-2 minutes is suspicious, since they would not have had time to read it, but 30 minutes is not.  Admins have tools which provide additional information which helps track voting fraud.  None of those tools were mentioned, implying that the moderator performed the action without justification.  It has been established that the question is good, so unless there is evidence of fraud, the votes should be returned.

Comment: @Trisped No, it hasn't. There are an **awful** lot of questions which fall under that "some people don't understand it" criterion. Should they really all be left open?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - don't be ridiculous.  People *without subject matter knowledge* not understanding a question is not a valid reason to close it, especially when a question is explicit about the problem to be solved.  Software Developers and Engineers by definition work in a specialized field requiring careful attention to detail - the target audience of questions is the people with the knowledge to answer them, not the overall set of humanity.  Elementary logic forces extending that to the varied awareness of specific subject matter *within* our field.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Your tag history does not support you as an expert at Android ROM development.  Neither does mine.  I have done some extremely limited Android ROM development and research, and I had the same question (though I never got far enough for it to matter).  Chris Stratton has a gold Android tag and has indicated that he does "_Custom Android builds, NDK, under-the-hood Android issues_" and has indicated that it is a good question.  His word (as a subject mater expert and experienced user) is sufficient unless challenged by a user with similar or better credentials.

Comment: Good point @Trisped. I should indeed take a step back on that and respect knowledge of a subject where it is obvious. I think what I really mean is more I don't know how to approach this, since it seems there are a lot of questions that fall under that and, possibly sadly, get closed by good willed people (as much as I can think I am) on topic they don't know.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That is understandable.  I believe the process is to have a user or multiple users with gold tags related to the question review it and pass judgement.  I am not sure what to search for to confirm this.

Comment: @Trisped at present the only administrative implication of subject area tags is the ability for a single non-moderator user to close a question as a duplicate, or reopen a question closed by a single such user.  They have no meaning in review, which may indeed be a design flaw, or at the least a design decision that requires reviewers to exercise extreme care.  Ideally, the "skip" button would be changed to "I'm not sure" as it is the only appropriate action when uncertainty exists.

Answer (score 37):

All you can do is report suspicious voting directly to us. Either flag or contact us directly. We'll look into it and make sure everything is running fairly. We can't provide details of the actions we take, but for a case where you already have a link directly to a specific post, you can easily determine what happened by just noting whether or not the votes got reversed.

In this case, all eight of the upvotes have been reversed and the score has been corrected.

Comment: Reverting the votes seem to be a fair call if it was fraudulent, but why was the question deleted altogether? `How to add widgets to home screen automatically?` seems to be a fair enough question to me. P.S: I didn't even have a chance to look at the original post, I am just picking it from the quoted text in this question, so there could be something else to warrant deletion.

Comment: what exactly *"votes got reversed"* mean? I look at the deleted question and it has exactly `8` downvotes. So the fraud upvotes is turned into downvotes like ghostrider turns peoples sins against them? I thought reversal meant just cancelling. Would be cool to have this Penance Stare effect for serial down votes :3

Comment: @TJ The upvotes were removed, so there are 0 of them left. The downvotes are from other users, probably from those who saw the question through this Meta discussion.

Comment: You indicated that the votes were reversed, but did not indicate what was fraudulent about them.  The only reasons for them to be fraudulent that I can see is TZHX comment to the original question (7 up votes in 30 minutes and no changes since).  I can think of 4 reasons this would happen without fraudulent voting.  I understand you cannot mention specifics, but is there other information (which only moderators have access to) which indicated that these votes were fraudulent?