# Failed audit on question that lacks a question

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I recently [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15465934) on this question:

> I have recently updated android studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3 and now can't see option of Launch Standalone SDK Manager as it is useful to check updated of tools , google play services etc...

I voted to close as *unclear what you're asking*, but I was told that there's nothing wrong with this question.

I'm not familiar with Android SDK tools or anything of the sort, but I feel this question... lacks a question. Is the OP looking for the option to launch the standalone manager, or update their tools, or downgrade their version, or find something similar in the new version?

I was surprised to find the question upvoted, and in that state. Should've I simply skipped this review because I'm unfamiliar with the tool?

Comment: yeah android tag is very dangerous as audits. I got [bitten](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323738/is-this-voting-fraud-or-how-to-understand-some-android-questions-version-of) [twice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299184/why-is-this-unclear-question-with-no-minimal-reproducible-example-or-error-messa). It seems android users are *very* upvote happy. In this precise case however, I'm not sure. Remove a few of the cruft and this borders on a legitimate version comparing question, which doesn't make it an obvious good question.

Answer (score 4):

You voted to close an easily editable ***implied*** question.

Finding:

> I have recently updated android studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3 and now can't see option of Launch Standalone SDK Manager as it is useful to check updated of tools, google play services etc...

You could have edited:

> I have recently updated Android Studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3 and now can't see the option of Launch Standalone SDK Manager. But it is useful to check updates of tools, Google Play services etc...
>
> Where can I find this option?

Apparently more than one upvoter/auditor saw and went with the implied question. You may want to revisit your decision to vote to close instead of fix. I do not think the sequence of events is in any way related to the subject matter.

Comment: So I should've said _Leave Open_? Or I should've left the queue, opened the question and then edited it? I want to know how to handle the question in the review queue, independent of whether I open the question and downvote / edit as appropriate

Comment: Tas, there is no ___should___. You decide on your own actions. But I find myself that from an ambiguous starting point like this positive actions (like __fix problem__) usually yield positive reactions, whereas negative actions (like __close-vote__) lead to negative. It is as if you decide the direction for the next person to follow.