# Have I gotten too soft with close reviews?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review-audits

I'm somewhat aware of [strange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299184/why-is-this-unclear-question-with-no-minimal-reproducible-example-or-error-messa) [voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323738/is-this-voting-fraud-or-how-to-understand-some-android-questions-version-of) patterns on Android questions, leading to very strange audits. This taught me a lot, the latter question made me be a bit less quick to close android questions.

In this case however, I don't understand why a specific question was kept in the review audits. I failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/23100165) Android question audit, and contrarily to the bad questions that were upvoted in my previous questions, this is actually a roughly ok question, with actual code, the error type, and an attempt at solving it.

It is worlds away from other bad question that are generally seen in review queues, or simply downvoted. In its current state, it features what we want from questions (I think).

Have I gotten too soft? In the same way that I realized I was not assessing questions correctly in the past, is there a reason this question is considered so bad?

It seems that the question was edited only after being deleted, but should that not bump it off the review audit list?

Comment: If you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/23100165), and said to yourself, "Looks OK!", then I'd say yes, you have definitely gotten your quality filter miscalibrated. At best, that needs some serious editing love. Beyond that, if you're unsure what a good [android] question should look like, there is always the "Skip" button. Or the filter option to focus on tags you are an expert in.

Comment: This is why I filter on tags that I know something about when reviewing (where possible).

Comment: Meta irony: @CodyGray hasn't earned any points on the [android] tag either :)

Comment: Yes, an achievement I’m quite proud of, @user000001. Thanks for noticing. I haven’t earned any rep in [php], either. As a result, I don’t routinely review posts on these topics. When I do, it’s via the mod flag queue, and that’s why we ask that such flags not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies. Moderators are not and cannot be domain experts on all domains.

Comment: I'm with you: this isn't a great question, but there's enough here that is answerable that it deserved to be reopened not deleted. (And I think your point was you don't understand how it ended up as a close vote audit given it'd been edited after closing, and I agree with that too.) I'm not an Android expert either but I think I can answer the first part at least: OP is calling AsyncTask.doInBackground thinking that kicks off the background thread, which is obviously wrong since that's calling the code they've written directly. From a quick Google they meant AsyncTask.execute.

Comment: @Rup I came to the same conclusion, also without even knowing the Android API. The question was edited after closure, so perhaps, it should have been re-opened after that. I thought, edited questions go to the re-open review queue automatically. But if they do not anymore, then edited questions should not be used as an audit.

Comment: @Holger Take a look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55818492/timeline). After closure, the question was edited twice. The first edit did not improve quality. The question went into the reopen queue but there were 4 votes to leave closed and 0 votes to reopen. So it left the queue still closed. (Correctly, IMO.) Then there was a 2nd edit which turned the question into the one we can see now (for those of us who can see deleted posts). If a question has been reviewed for reopening once, further edits don't put it back into the queue.

Comment: The [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55818492/revisions) is especially noteworthy here. My *gut* reaction is that this looks like a code dump, but not knowing much about Android, it's hard for me to distinguish if that's an MCVE or not. Does it reproduce the problem reliably?

Comment: @jpmc26 while it would be perfect, if every question provided a stand-alone example, this is not a hard requirement. [As said by Rup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385504/have-i-gotten-too-soft-with-close-reviews?noredirect=1#comment700070_385504), the code is sufficient to understand what the OP did wrong.

Comment: @Louis unfortunately, this is another point why improving a bad question is not worth it. You don’t get rid of downvotes, as downvoters don’t get notified when the post has been edited (and rarely come back for revision on their own), and as you said, improving further after review does not bring it back to review queue either. Well, and as said, such a question should never become an audit then.

Comment: Even after edit question is still beyond bad. There is zillion examples out there on how to use AsyncTask and it seems that OP didn't read any of them, nor the zillion posts on NetworkOnMainThreadException that usually also contain working examples on how to use AsyncTask. It is basically give me the codes question (or give me tutorial) because posted code is as good as random trash. At best it would be poor dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: @Holger I disagree. It is a hard requirement if you're going to dump code at us; the situations not requiring an MCVE are ones where you wouldn't post your own code at all. If you can't reduce your broken code to a standalone example (maybe minus well known boilerplate), it's Too Broad. If the user performed a common error or just failed at performing a common task, then it almost certainly is a duplicate as well. We don't need a question for every possible variation of, "I screwed up performing common task X. Fix it for me."

Comment: Perhaps you should be more careful in reviewing technology that you are not familiar with. I have worked with android in the past, and there are some critical pieces missing with this code, as well as a whole host of issues with how to create them and still be inline with the intent of the question. I think that the unclear closure was appropriate here, since it is impossible from the structure to know what the outcome should be without guessing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As [discussed in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385504/have-i-gotten-too-soft-with-close-reviews#comment700156_385504), the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55818492/timeline) is important here. The question was edited twice after closure, but the first edit was not sufficient to pass the reopen review. The second edit brought the question into the form you saw, not the best one in the world, but perhaps worth reopening, but it didn’t bring it back into the review queue again.

To me, it looks like a serious flaw of the audit system if it presents you with a question that has been edited since the last review, but expects you to make the same decision as the other reviewers, based on a different content.

Comment: The Audit system picks targets largely based on vote score. It's a "Damned if you do, damned if you don't scenario". On the one hand, it tends to give you a decent review pool of questions to trip reviewers up. On the other, voters gonna vote, regardless of quality. Should an edit drop it out of audits? Possibly, but votes have never been an indicator of quality anyways

Comment: @Machavity The fact that audits might be designed to trip reviewers up would make review queues unappealing to everyone, especially the people we want reviewing.

Comment: @jpmc26 Don't get me wrong. I'm not saying it's a *good* system, just that edits are not necessarily indicators that the quality improved

Comment: @Machavity Yes, but I understand Holger's point. Votes that occurred prior to an edit may not be reflective of its current quality, either in the positive or negative direction. The audit system is crappy and frustrating. It's probably driving even good reviewers away. I know it made me decide to stop trying to use them.

Comment: @Machavity of course, edits don’t necessarily improve the quality of the post, but an audit system picking up posts automatically must consider that it doesn’t know what an edit did, so it can’t say that a reviewer does wrong, when it has no knowledge about the quality. That can be also go into the other direction, a good post could have been vandalized by the last edit, but a reviewer is supposed to say that what they see was a good post, because that’s the last state the audit system knows.

Comment: @Machavity Audits should consist only of posts which the system has as confident as possible a judgement about their quality. Once it's been edited, that should remove a lot of that confidence, thus it's no longer a good candidate for automatic audit selection. The audit system should consist of unambiguously good and bad posts only. It is not there to make judgements on every single post.