# Suspended from reviewing based on questions that are just error messages

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I have been suspended from reviewing for failing these review audits:

- On September 8: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29774769
- On September 22: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29895994

[image: Screenshot of review ban message]

Are these really good questions? Both are error messages without context or code.

Comment: hmm... Why would posts that have been downvoted be directly used as "good question" audits

Comment: It's probably because the net score is still positive, so the system "thinks" it's a "good question". It isn't, it's missing the "*Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve*" part of how to ask a good question, and the system can't check for that :(

Comment: dayum, the android vote brigade is never ending. I've had [similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299184) [problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323738) in the past.

Comment: Cool, SO recreated an [old bug that just got fixed a few months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment). A comment shouldn't fail the audit even if the system thinks the question is good.

Comment: Yes, those are ... poor ... audits. I've lifted your review suspension. Unfortunately, other than close the questions (already done), there's not much which we can directly do to prevent them from being audits.

Comment: Thank you, @Makyen! I really appreciate the work elected moderators do here, and I know there are a _lot_ of things competing for your attention. Keep up the good work.

Comment: 'We suspect that you are not actually reviewing tasks'. Nice. To that I would say: 'I suspect you are not actually auditing reviews'.

Comment: @Chris np. I'm happy to help. Once aware of it, taking a look at your situation didn't take all that much effort. The thing that took substantial time was looking through the 60+ other reviews/audits with these two questions looking for anyone else that was tripped up by them and who had been suspended, then evaluating why each user was suspended and if their other reviews justified the suspension, even if one of these two contributed to it. [Along with multiple side-trips into adding to and/or fixing userscripts which make doing that a bit easier, but still considerable time/effort.]

Comment: @Makyen: Oh good. I don't have to explain the nuclear option again.

Comment: This is why I have stopped visiting review queues altogether. I've been bitten by bad audits and unclear instructions. Now I stick to contributing my time where it is appreciated.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

These are ***terrible*** audits.  You were right to vote to close.

I'm quite surprised these were selected, because they've been downvoted before being used as audits.  I'd speculate that the audit selection criteria are weaker for First Questions (I note that these posts haven't been used as close/reopen audits), and probably should be made stricter.

The problem here is that when a library/tool/framework release causes a widespread bug, a question is often posted with no description of how to reproduce said bug.  People with the same problem then upvote those questions after finding them, rather than creating a question with a minimal, reproducible example.  When someone figures out how to fix it, they post it on the highly upvoted question, making it an effective canonical question.  This creates an unfortunate situation where the canonical question has absolutely no information on how to reproduce the bug.  Ideally, this would be caught quickly (maybe via first questions review!) and remedied before it happens.  But these posts certainly shouldn't be used as audits, and if I were a moderator, I'd lift a review suspension brought on by failing audits like that.

Comment: "and if I were a moderator".. Just start writing the nomination post ;)

Comment: But seriously, I'd vote for you if you were in the election (maybe 2nd or 3rd if a more experienced flower were to nominate, if you know what I mean).

Comment: The most helpful response was [a comment from @Makyen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411695/suspended-from-reviewing-based-on-questions-that-are-just-error-messages#comment869249_411695), but I can't accept comments. This answer was also very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Side note: if a situation like that happens where a no-context error message becomes a canonical, that's when someone should edit the question, perhaps even porting over content from another question if someone ever did ask a proper [mcve] involving the same error, if they know the answer matches that case.  Or if they know about it being a bug introduced in some version of something, edit that into the title.

Answer (score 9):

I have also got a lot of terrible  audits like these. And now, if I get a user without a link in the username, I would  see the real votes of the question/answer first before I take action.

Maybe the moderators need to review the audit before it goes to the review queue as an audit. Don't just use random high-vote posts without know that eligible or not to be the review audit.

Comment: I suggest adding some sort of probation time to the audit questions, if users consistently fail the review above a certain threshold, it should be reviewed by a moderator or removed altogether.

Comment: @MarcSances Personally, I'd love to see Brad's suggestion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/165261) implemented.

Answer (score -10):

Stack Exchange Inc., via Stack Overflow the platform, has made it very clear that they value garbage over quality. They've also made it clear that they aren't willing to invest in the Stack Overflow platform to accommodate the shift from quality to garbage. The end result is this farcical situation where the platform is now punishing people who are trying to get rid of garbage.

This is not by design but by incompetence, yet it also fundamentally reflects the view that Stack Exchange Inc. has of curators, and such occurrences are only going to get worse as more garbage flows in to the site.

Personally, I would've taken it as a sign to stop curating altogether.

Comment: I've been quite vocal about issues with the new review changes myself, but how is spending a bunch of developer timing working on curation tools _not_ "investing in the Stack Overflow platform"?  They're also building a curator support team in the Community team.

Comment: @RyanM I'd like to introduce to you the concept of "window dressing".

Comment: @RyanM Bad developer time is worse than no developer time.

Comment: [An appropriate musical que](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVS8OHmlFtE)

Comment: This all might be true, and I share your sentiments. However, you seem to be holding some serious angst about this place... It's not all that healthy :)

Comment: Healthier than some alternatives. Not a huge fan of shooting rampages.

Comment: You seem to be a *very* glass half empty kind of person ;) Apart from you being wrong in the fact that they're not investing time and resources on curating and curators, I think the real issue is that they're trying to accommodate for quantity instead of quality. While they did rework the queues, I think they did it.. badly. To me, it's making me less motivated to do any curating.