# Is this no-code question review audit right?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I just failed [this Close Vote Queue audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/33190825). I chose to close for needing more debugging details, but it seems the audit says that this question is fine as-is, even though the question only had two error messages and no code. My thinking was that one would not be able to answer this question without code. This seems to be similar to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411695/suspended-from-reviewing-based-on-questions-that-are-just-error-messages).

So, is the question legitimately good as-is despite no code, or is the audit wrong?

Comment: What possible code do you think clarifies a build issue? The "only two error messages" don't point to code failing to compile (you know, where you might want to see the code) but clearly shows it's some sort of dependency issue where a dependency shows up twice. Does the code of the application make *any* difference to where the dependencies are pulled from? Or do you want to see the code of the third party dependencies even though that's also irrelevant as 1. it's the build system that at focus here 2. the build system uses the artefacts, rather than the code of the dependencies?

Comment: "but it seems the audit says that this question is fine as-is" - Let's not give audits that much credit. The only thing that was done here was pick a question which was not closed and has no close votes and then you were shown a lie. That's it. This time it might not be true that the question is close worthy, but you are 100% guaranteed to find them if you keep reviewing, easily. There are too many incoming questions for all close worthy questions to actually be closed.

Answer (score 11):

It's a build configuration problem in a very specific domain.  What good would knowing the code that is intended to be built actually do here?

If you google around a bit, you'll notice that this exception does occur in a few other places, most notably [the official react-native GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35204).

Furthermore, because the error message is referring to shared libraries (.so files), this would isolate the issue into being something on the machine that it's running on not being set up, and would completely eliminate the code itself as being the root cause of any issues.

So I think this audit was OK.  It demonstrated that the routine pattern of "no code == off-topic question" is not always applicably true, and it encourages you to stay a bit more cautious and aware when it comes to questions like this.

Comment: *[wily](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wily#Adjective)* - *1. [Sly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sly#Adjective), [cunning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cunning#Adjective), full of tricks.* Is there another meaning?

Comment: Maybe I was going for "cautious".  I'll edit!