# Is it acceptable to award bounty to a colleague?

Tags: support, bounty

One of my colleagues has seen my question on SO and mentioned that he's got a good answer. There's already another answer, rather short and not bounty-like but still. My colleague had some further ideas that actually solved the problem (the already posted answer by someone else is a part of the final solution).

Should I ask my friend to post the answer? And if so, should I bounty the other guy?

Comment: Encouraging people to post good answers is always good. It's your collected rep so you do what you please with it. Still, I'd say no - do not bounty your friend. Partly because he's got info that the other users don't have by simply talking to you (unfair advantage). Partly, because there's always the haunting suspicion that it's a voting ring and fishy cooperation.

Comment: In the past when I solved the problem of SO users that I know outside of SO and they suggested I answer the question they posted on SO, I've given them the okay to edit what I gave them and post it as a self-answer. Chances are that if this happens once, it is going to happen again and there's a point beyond which our combined activity history may look suspicious. I prefer not to start down that road. Some of them sometimes deleted their question and suggested I post a self-answered one. There was no active bounty involved though.

Comment: Different question, but basically the same answer as [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323600/is-it-ok-if-a-colleague-adds-a-bounty-to-my-question). If you're using the system correctly, then it is not a problem. It *certainly* isn't a problem if it only happens occasionally. Ask yourself: does having this answer improve the site for everyone? If it does, upvote that answer and award the bounty with gusto—the person who posted it deserves the accolades, even if they work with you. If your intentions are pure, then you have nothing to feel bad about.

Comment: Short answer: As long as you are awarding the content and not the person you should be fine.

Comment: ```he's got a good answer``` vs```rather short and not bounty-like``` and why not talk to a colleague before posting to SO?

Comment: @MichalStefanow, due to the lack of information here, we could assume that he may not have known his colleague knew the information until later. If this is relating to a programming question, it's possible he wasn't aware that the colleague knew the language. This is all speculative, but it holds reason. I might ask people more intelligent than I on certain subjects through the internet about advice or information before asking my friend down the street who may not even know the difference between Guana and Guano (metaphorically). Stupid example, but viable none-the-less.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The only time you'd fall under scrutiny using the bounty system is if we detect that you're using it to transfer reputation to multiple accounts that *you* control. It's not a very efficient way to do it, but remains one of the ways that sock puppet rings try to take advantage of the system.

Hence, I wouldn't go awarding a *ton* of bounties to people that (1) benefit from a large share of your upvotes and (2) work from the same place that you do. To a moderator, that would look .. a tad bit sketchy :) I caught more than a few rings when I noticed a large bounty given to a *really* awful answer.

As long is the answer is of good quality, and you don't otherwise target your votes specifically to your coworkers, you don't have anything to worry about; it's your rep, spend it any way you like.

Comment: Same workplace. Also, he's helped me before so there's definitely a track record of "appreciation". Following your advice, I won't bounty him. Regrettably, we're heading into a situation where the bounty will be given to a very short and unbounty'ish reply while a more extensive and fully working one won't be posted at all. (I might post one myself but that's another story...) Thanks for the suggestion, bro!